# Finding the Joint from the Connected Body

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to find the Joint that holds my Rigidbody, through the rigidbody?

Allow me to clarify more
I have my *GameObject* and it has a *FixedJoint* which has a *Rigidbody* attached to it (the connectedBody) and what I want to do is to find the FixedJoint, by looking for it from the Rigidbody.

Reason to why I want to do this is because I want my Joint to break when my Rigidbody hits something hard enough. I can't use BreakForce as it's checked all the time, so if I turn my original object fast enough it will break.

Comment: What about `gameObject.GetComponent<FixedJoint> ()` or `gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<FixedJoint> ()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through the `Rigidbody`, unfortunately there isn't. Given the `FixedJoint`, you can check its [`connectedBody`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Joint-connectedBody.html) property, but you can't check it the other way around.

Don't forget, though, that you can always attach a custom component.

Something like this would be simple enough:

```
public class FixedJointConnection : MonoBehaviour {
    public FixedJoint joint;
}
```

When you attach the joint, you can also attach a `FixedJointConnection` and set the `joint` reference.

You can even write a helper function to do just that:

```
public static FixedJointConnection Connect(Rigidbody anchor, Rigidbody child) {
    FixedJoint joint = child.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
    joint.connectedBody = anchor;
    joint.connectedAnchor = anchor.transform.InverseTransformPoint(child.transform.position);

    //TODO: any more joint config? depends on your game

    FixedJointConnection connection = anchor.AddComponent<FixedJointConnection>();
    connection.joint = joint;

    return connection;
}
```

From there, you can add a check during each collision:

- Do we have any `FixedJointConnection`(s) attached?
- If so, did we hit hard enough to break them?

Depending on what exactly you need, your custom component class can be very simple or fairly complex. Doesn't matter, though; the point here is just that Unity's components provide powerful features, and that you can amplify those features by writing your own.

Comment: This is what I had in mind for a 2nd solution, I was hoping there was one already built-in. Thanks though!